# Wikipedia online access

Tags: java, wikipedia

I'm looking for an efficient solution to access Wikipedia online using JAVA in order to extract some content from articles (>100 articles) without being blocked. Thanks in advace for any given help.

Comment: You can download entire wikipedia. Its only around 20GB.

Comment: What are you looking exactly? Program or logic or what? What help are you searching ?

Comment: Are you looking for getting around your internet access restriction mechanism ?

Comment: I'm looking for a Java Api. I have used Jsoup and my projects blocks after extracting some articles (<10) showing me a list of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the information in any mediawiki by using the public [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page). Depending on the amount of interaction with Wikipedia, you might want to get an user account with a "bot" flag.